# Assign the value returned by a method to a handle.

Tags: drools

I have a rule similar to the following. I need to assign the value returned by my matcher to a handler to be used elsewhere. How can I do that? Thank you.

```
package a.b.c 

import java.util.List; 

import a.b.Matcher; 
import a.b.Container; 
import a.b.TestObject1; 
import a.b.TestObject2; 

global Matcher myMatcher; 
global Container container; 

when 
        $x1: TestObject1( 
                $x1_1 : id, (id in ("11", "16", "140")) 
        ) 

        $x2: TestObject2( 
                $x2_2: id, myMatcher.match(id, container.getContainer(100)) != null
         ) 

then 
        //print. 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no straightforward way to do that. 
2 options are:

1. Call myMatcher.match() again in the RHS of the rule. This could be problematic if the match() method execution is expensive.
2. Create a different rule calculating the match() value for all your TestObject2 facts:

   ```
   rule 'Calculate match value'
       $t: TestObject2()
   when
       TestObject2Match m = new TestObject2Match($t); // -> you must define this class
       m.setMatchValue(myMatcher.match($t.getId(), container.getContainer(100)));

       insertLogical(m);
   then
   ```

Now, the rule you previously had must be rewritten as follows:

```
    rule '...'
        $x1: TestObject1( 
            $x1_1 : id, (id in ("11", "16", "140")) 
        ) 
        $m: TestObject2Match(matchValue != null)
    when
        //print $m.getMatchValue()
    then
```

Hope it helps,